# AngularJS : Directive Isolated Scoping

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a AngularJS Directive that is a table.  The parent most control `ng-table` needs to have a isolated scope for its options and model.

However, the children should 'inherit' that scope so that you don't have to pass tons of options to a very interconnected group of components.

For example:

```
 <div ng-table="tableOptions" ng-model="results">

    <div ng-table-header>
        <div ng-table-header-column="column" 
             ng-repeat="column in tableOptions.columns">
            {{column.name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-table-body>

        <div ng-table-row="row"
             ng-repeat="row in $results">

            <div ng-table-cell="column"
                 ng-repeat="column in tableOptions.columns">

                {{row[column.id]}}

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div ng-table-footer></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, `ng-table-header`, `ng-header-column`, etc all need to access properties from the parent control `ng-table`.  Furthermore, all the directives `replace` and `transclude`.

I know I could `broadcast` events to the children/parent directives but is there a better way to restrict scope at the parent level and auto pass it to the children?

Comment: Define ng-table to have isolated scope (scope: {}), and have the child directives have child scope (scope: true).  This way, the child directives will inherit scope variables all the way up to the isolated parent scope.

Comment: Just a note: Angular docs recommend to avoid prefixing proprietary directives with the `ng-` prefix, since you could run into problems if they roll their own implementation of `ng-table`. Better to use your own prefix there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a work around looking at angular-ui code that created their own transclude directive to apply scope.

so my master `table` directive starts off like:

```
module.directive('ngTable', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $window, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true, // NOTE THIS
        replace: true, // NOTE THIS
        templateUrl: 'common/components/table/views/table.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            tableOptions: "=ngTable"
        },
        controller: 'ngTableCtrl',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, controller, ngModel) {
            ....
        }
     }
});
```

then I create my own transclude directive like:

```
module.directive('tableTransclude', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude) {
            $transclude($scope, function (clone) {
                $element.empty();
                $element.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

and the usage in the template of table looks like:

```
<div table-transclude />
```

And presto!!!  A little hacky but gets the job done.  I understand why Angular did this but in some cases you need this type of scoping.

Answer (score 1):

*Oh dude, you have forced me to look how forms and inputs directives are implemented in angular.*

So, angularjs has similar thing to what you want to implement - **ng-form** directive with **ng-input**.

When you use `form` or `ng-form` directive, it creates **controller**(directives can do it) and transclude html-code will inherit it. `ng-input`(`input`) asks for it in `require` option.

```
require: ['ngModel', '^?form', '^?ngModelOptions'],
```

So you get this controller in `link` function. So... you can call functions, do things, you know.

You can do it like this(just an idea, this is how it works):

```
.directive('coolTable', function() {
  return {
    ...
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.columns = [];  /* Here you will have all table columns, so you can send it's data to service and do any work */
        $scope.registerColumn = function(column) {
            $scope.columns.push(column);
        };
    },
    ...
  };
})


.directive('column', function() {
  return {
    ...
    require: '^?coolTable',
    ...
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, coolTable) {
        coolTable.registerColumn(this);
    },
  };
})


<coolTable>
    <column></column>
    <column></column>
    <column></column>
</coolTable>
```

Comment: Can you expand on the `registerColumn` method usage?

Comment: It is up to you. You can collect columns directives in controller or collect just column names, you can trigger "sortBy" of table from directive or do anything else!

Comment: what about `angular.extend` in register to copy the table scope props to the column ... or something to that respect atleast

Comment: Look, as I see(you can point where I'm wrong), you want to make column able to modify data, for example, sort it by `this` column, of search by `this` column. Or turn page on pagination click in `table-footer`. All these functions can be archived easily, think about it like "talking" between directive and table itself. From column, you should call `orderBy` of table, from footer, you should call `goTo` of table. All these methods you can define in controller of the table directive. So, there is no reason to inherit it. But you can do whatever you want, you could have great idea too!